# LoginWithRedirect is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, auth0

I'm following the complete guide to Auth0 with React.
https://auth0.com/blog/complete-guide-to-react-user-authentication/#Add-User-Authentication

For some reason i am getting "Login with redirect is not a function" and i'm fairly sure i have my setup right according to their guide.

```
LoginButton.jsx

import React from 'react';
import { useAuth0 } from 'auth0-react';

const LoginButton = () => {
  const { loginWithRedirect } = useAuth0();
  return (
    <button
      className="btn btn-primary btn-block"
      onClick={() => loginWithRedirect()}
    >
      Log In
    </button>
  );
};

export default LoginButton;
```

The error im getting:

```
×
TypeError: loginWithRedirect is not a function
onClick
C:/Users/JackJ/source/repos/ReactApp/src/Auth/LoginButton.jsx:9
   6 | return (
   7 |   <button
   8 |     className="btn btn-primary btn-block"
>  9 |     onClick={() => loginWithRedirect()}
     | ^  10 |   >
  11 |     Log In
  12 |   </button>
View compiled
▼ 19 stack frames were expanded.
HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback
C:/Users/JackJ/source/repos/ReactApp/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev
C:/Users/JackJ/source/repos/ReactApp/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback
C:/Users/JackJ/source/repos/ReactApp/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4056
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError
C:/Users/JackJ/source/repos/ReactApp/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4070
executeDispatch
C:/Users/JackJ/source/repos/ReactApp/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:8243
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder
C:/Users/JackJ/source/repos/ReactApp/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:8275
processDispatchQueue
C:/Users/JackJ/source/repos/ReactApp/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:8288
dispatchEventsForPlugins
C:/Users/JackJ/source/repos/ReactApp/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:8299
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/JackJ/source/repos/ReactApp/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:8508
batchedEventUpdates$1
C:/Users/JackJ/source/repos/ReactApp/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22396
batchedEventUpdates
C:/Users/JackJ/source/repos/ReactApp/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3745
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem
C:/Users/JackJ/source/repos/ReactApp/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:8507
attemptToDispatchEvent
C:/Users/JackJ/source/repos/ReactApp/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:6005
dispatchEvent
C:/Users/JackJ/source/repos/ReactApp/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:5924
unstable_runWithPriority
```

I've checked all appropriate callback URL's are in the allowed section, and when i hover over the Auth0 i see:
[image: Context import]

[image: error debug]

I can't understand why this is happening, it's imported correctly "supposedly" yet you hover over loginWithRedirect and its to ":Any" ? yet Auth0 wrote the code..

i have no idea what i'm doing so i'mr eally not sure how to proceed or what to attempt, scouring stack and google for similar errors was a no go.

If anyone could contribute and help me with this itd be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you can use ``const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();`` where you will check is user auth or not? If yes, use ``history`` in react-router and redirect the user where you want?

Comment: The guide has `import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";` please try that

Comment: Hi Vitalii, That was giving me a module not found error, the current import location resolved that error

Comment: @jackjsmith1988 The issue seems to be with `useAuth0` not being a function, try `console.log(useAuth0);` to see what are you getting with an import (I expect `undefined`). I'd suggest installing as `npm install @auth0/auth0-react` and importing from `@auth0/auth0-react`.

Comment: when i console.logged both loginWithRedirect and UseAuth0, both returned the same error as above in the debug console. Is not a function.

additionally, when i hover the node module path, i see that VSC recognises it as:

/node_modules/auth0-react/dist/index

If you are using this as well, can you check to see if your path resolves the same please?

Comment: Vitalii, please can you re-write your comment in your answer so i can mark it green?

Thanks a lot mate :-)

Comment: @jackjsmith1988 `auth0-react` and `@auth0/auth0-react` are completely different packages. I had to install both to reproduce. First resolves to `node_modules/auth0-react/dist/index"` and second to `@auth0/auth0-react/dist/index"`. When I was installing `auth0-react` I've got this deprecation message: `npm WARN deprecated auth0-react@3.1.0: This package is deprecated in favor of @auth0/auth0-react — the official SDK for React Single Page Applications provided directly by Auth0 that should be used instead: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@auth0/auth0-react`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please install `npm install @auth0/auth0-react` and import like:

```
import { useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react';
```

Looks like `auth0-react` and `@auth0/auth0-react` are completely different libraries.

First one resolves to `node_modules/auth0-react/dist/index` during import and second to `@auth0/auth0-react/dist/index`.

When I was installing `auth0-react` I've got the following deprecation message:

```
npm WARN deprecated auth0-react@3.1.0: This package is deprecated in favor of
@auth0/auth0-react — the official SDK for React Single Page Applications
provided directly by Auth0 that should be used instead: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@auth0/auth0-react
```